# .tagName property for immediate elements?

Tags: javascript, html

Does the `.tagName` property work for immediate elements? I have been getting it to work using child elements as a jump-off point, but I can't get it to work on immediate elements.

---

Here is an example that works:

**HTML**

```
<p>This is paragraph 1.</p>
<p>This is paragraph 2.</p>
<p>This is paragraph 3.</p>
<p>This is paragraph 4.</p>
<div>
    <p id="foo">This is paragraph 5.</p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
(function(){

var el = document.getElementById("foo");

    var name = el.parentNode.tagName;

    alert(name);

}());
```

This gets me the name of the div element and this is what I want to achieve, but is there a shorter way?

I don't want to add an identifier to the element and target it that way, this is because I don't want to add unnecessary mark-up to my HTML document. Here is an example that works, but relies on an identifier.

---

**HTML**

```
<p>This is paragraph 1.</p>
<p>This is paragraph 2.</p>
<p>This is paragraph 3.</p>
<p>This is paragraph 4.</p>
<div id="bar">
   <p id="foo">This is paragraph 5.</p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
(function(){

var el = document.getElementById("bar");

    var name = el.tagName;

    alert(name);

}());
```

As you see this get's the desired effect, but relies on an identifier. So I thought: "Can't I use the `.tagName` property on the element itself and target the element with `.getElementsByTagName()`?"

---

**HTML**

```
<p>This is paragraph 1.</p>
<p>This is paragraph 2.</p>
<p>This is paragraph 3.</p>
<p>This is paragraph 4.</p>
<div>
    <p id="foo">This is paragraph 5.</p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
(function(){

var el = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

    var name = el.tagName;

    alert(name);

}());
```

The answer is no. This get's me a value of `undefined`. Why is this? Anyone have a solution?
Link to jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BV5EP/

Comment: "I don't want to add unnecessary mark-up to my HTML document" - if you need to target the element from JS or CSS, then perhaps it's not "unnecessary"...

Comment: @bfavaretto good point, but let's say you litter your HTML document with many classes and ID's. You think to yourself: "nothing wrong with that", well yes there is. You do get fine-grained control over everything, but there are more smarter way of targeting those elements, like using a combination of type and descendant selectors, child selectors, attribute selectors you name it. This way your html stays clean and semantic.

Comment: Yes, I said "perhaps"; it's a delicate balance of several factors. Note that classes and ids can also be used to add semantic value to the markup.

Comment: Why would you need to get the `tagName` from an element returned from `getElementsByTagName()`?

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that `getElementsbyTagName` (notice the plural **s**) returns a `nodeList` instead of an `Element` (like `getElementById` does). You need to make sure to use `el[0].tagName`!

<kbd>**[Corrected Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BV5EP/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: +1 Great answer! I knew it returned a nodeList and that, nodeList are similar to arrays, but it hadn't crossed my mind to target them.

Comment: It returns a NodeList, not an Array.

Comment: @Blue Skies, yes I said that they return nodeLists and that they are similar to arrays, I did not say that they return arrays.

Comment: But I said it returned an `Array`. Which is not exactly true, so I changed that. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @BlueSkies I thought you said that to me, sorry!

Comment: @kozlovski5: I should have given an proper @ notification. :)

Answer (score 1):

> This get's me a value of undefined. Why is this?

Because the NodeList that getElementsByTagName returns has no tagname property.

> Anyone have a solution?

You have to access the elements that the NodeList contains by index – `el[0].tagName` in this case, if you only want to access the first (or only) div element.